# html form with post method indirectly points to authentication code

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, submit

I am planning on creating a new webpage, and have chosen a page-of-interest to serve as a template. I have downloaded every page source possible in order to thoroughly analyse the structure and functionality of the page before starting my own project. However, after some hours of back-and-forth checking, and rechecking, I honestly cannot figure out the login function of the target page:

After stripping down html formatting, the login form looks like this:

```
<form id=frmLogin method=post name=frmLogin action=/login/>
    <input id=strID tabIndex=1 type=text name=strID>
    <input id=strPW tabIndex=2 type=password name=strPW>
    <div class="cpBtn panel" onclick="return fnChkFrmLg();"><p>LOG IN</p></div>
</form>
```

As you can see, it contains a pretty straight forward form. After entering a username and password, and clicking on 'LOG IN' button, a short JS-based function 'fnChkFrmLg();' is triggered. Respective code snippet for the said JS looks like this:

```
function fnChkFrmLg() {
if (document.frmLogin.strID.value.length == 0 || document.frmLogin.strID.value == "Username") {
    alert ('Please enter a valid username.');
    frmLogin.strID.value = "";
    frmLogin.strID.focus();
    return false;
}
if (document.frmLogin.strPW.value.length == 0 || document.frmLogin.strPW.value == "Password") {
    alert ('Please enter a valid password.');
    frmLogin.strPW.value = "";
    frmLogin.strPW.focus();
    return false;
}
document.frmLogin.submit();
return true;
```

}

The above function only checks if the user has indeed entered a valid username and password,  submits the above form 'frmLogin', and returns true.

The login form that the webpage is using is pretty much a 'by-the-book' way of handling the first bit of authentication protocol. Once the form is submitted, it is directed to /login/, which should contain all the necessary code for contacting a DB, checking if the submitted username and password exist/are correct, and then either rejecting connection, or loading up account page with all the necessary data. However, what boggles my mind is that the /login/ source code is nowhere NEAR to be found. With that being said, can anyone explain what is going on, and/or how to retrieve the missing bit of code for the authentication protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute in your form is set to wrong path.
I bit that it will login/index.php (of course if you use php)

Comment: The code snippet is copied from a fully functional page, and does not seem to point to anything. Although, once logged in, the user is taken to www.somewebpage.com/account/ instead of www.somewebpage.com/login or similar...

Comment: I have now checked if Semsem's prediction was correct. The said page does not exist, and results in '404'. Other similar address combinations resulted in '404' as well.

Answer (score 0):

After a more in-depth research I found out that the said webpage is using directory redirection via 'redirect' command in the .htaccess file. As such, the whole authentication processes are handled internally, behind users 'eyes', and returned as /account/ directory (the user's profile page).

Comment: just testing what will happen